# How to avoid inactive sessions using wso2 connection pool on oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a small set of custom WSO2 ESB mediators which use an oracle database to which I'm connecting via WSO2 Data Source like this:

```html
 private void Connect(boolean isRetry) throws SQLException {  
     DataSource ds = null;
     
  try {
   Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
         environment.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.jndi.CarbonJavaURLContextFactory");
         Context initContext = new InitialContext(environment);
         ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jndi/kernel");
  } catch (NamingException e) {
   throw new SQLException("Connection pool exception", e);
  }
     
  // Nawiazanie polaczenia
     this.connection = ds.getConnection();
  this.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
 }
```

After using the connection I'm closing it like this:

```html
 public void Close() throws SQLException {
  try {
   if (this.connection != null) {
    this.connection.close();
    this.connection = null;
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   System.out.println(" @@ Failed to close the connection!");
   e.printStackTrace();
   throw e;
  } 
 }
```

Every custom mediator is using the above Connect method on the begining and Close method in the finally scope at the end.

In a single sequence (executed by a message processor) there are at least 2 custom mediators called, sometimes even 5.

The problem is that when there are a lot of messages passing through the queue there are hundreds of inactive session on the database (oracle). It looks like the Connect method doesn't try to get an inactive connection and use it and I thought that this is the whole point of having a connection pool.

Any help will be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had "test on idle" set to true. After turning it off everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a custom mediator that needs to get a connection on oracle db.
I don't have this problem of inactive sessions although this mediator is used in a sequence executed by a message processor (processing thousands of messages)

Don't know exactly what is wrong in your case but I hope this can help you :

- the datasource is defined in WSO2 ESB with the web console.
- The Driver used is oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
- A validation query is defined (select 1 from dual)
- test on borrow is set to true
- max active is a positive number
- remove abandoned is set to true
- and of course, the data source is exposed as a JNDI Data Source

In the java part, I don't use directly InitialContext to made a lookup : I use org.apache.synapse.commons.datasource.DataSourceFinder.find(dataSourceName, jndiProperties) where jndiProperties is just a new Properties()

In the finally, I just need to close resultset, statement and connection

It works well with ESB 4.8.1 and ESB 5

Comment: Maybe using InitialContext is my problem, I'll try that :)